# LEFT Join PSQL where the AND parameter is on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a PSQL query where the AND parameter in the left join in on another table check table sample below.

Invoices

```
 id  | account |      invoice_date       | reference | total_amount | status 
-----+---------+-------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------
 164 |     100 | 2016-08-03 03:05:08.996 |       161 |      2000.00 |       
 165 |     100 | 2016-08-03 21:42:07.865 |       164 |            0 |       
 167 |     100 | 2016-08-03 22:56:41.731 |       166 |       100.00 |       
 168 |     100 | 1970-01-01 00:33:20     |       161 |          200 |       
 169 |     100 | 2016-08-08 00:00:00     |       161 |          200 |
```

Invoice_items

```
 id  | invoice | invoice_item_type | product | quantity | unit_price | reference | amount  
-----+---------+-------------------+---------+----------+------------+-----------+---------
 143 |     164 |                 1 |       6 |          |            |       161 | 2000.00
 144 |     165 |                 1 |      11 |          |            |       164 |       0
 145 |     167 |                 1 |       8 |          |            |       166 |  100.00
```

There is also another table PRODUCTS but the only relevant field there is id

this is my query

```
select products.id, sum(invoice_items.amount) as total_revenue
from products
    left join invoice_items on invoice_items.product = products.id
    left join invoices on invoice_items.invoice = invoices.id
                      and invoices.invoice_date= current_date
group by products.id;
```

What i need the query to do is to list all Product ids and on the total_revenue column, put the sum of sales for the product (add 'amount' in invoice_items table where 'product' field is similar) for the current day (found on INVOICES table). But when i run this query it lists all total_amounts for the products. What am i missing?

Sample output. 8 , 6 and 11 must be empty

```
id  | total_revenue 
-----+---------------
 125 |              
 154 |              
 119 |              
 129 |              
   8 |        100.00
 112 |              
   5 |              
 132 |              
 104 |              
 113 |              
 143 |              
 152 |              
 121 |              
 127 |              
 165 |              
 139 |              
 146 |              
  15 |              
   2 |              
 147 |              
 149 |              
 166 |              
 169 |              
  13 |              
 106 |              
 122 |              
   9 |              
  11 |             0
 110 |              
 120 |              
 130 |              
 155 |              
 134 |              
 136 |              
 101 |              
 168 |              
 131 |              
 157 |              
 161 |              
 103 |              
 150 |              
 159 |              
 107 |              
 108 |              
 145 |              
   4 |              
  12 |              
 158 |              
 167 |              
 138 |              
 162 |              
 100 |              
 156 |              
 163 |              
 124 |              
 123 |              
 109 |              
 153 |              
 102 |              
 105 |              
 151 |              
 116 |              
 133 |              
 140 |              
 160 |              
 148 |              
 126 |              
 141 |              
   7 |              
 118 |              
  10 |              
 164 |              
 128 |              
  14 |              
 144 |              
 135 |              
   1 |              
   6 |       2000.00
   3 |              
 137 |              
 117 |              
 142 |              
 111 |
```

Comment: What do you mean by _8 , 6 and 11 must be empty_. Since you have `and` for the date in the `left join` it will add back the products which did not match. Looking at your query, even a inner join should be sufficient if you only want the revenues for products which have an invoice against them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date constraint is only filtering out records in the invoices table, whereas you need it to also filter out the records in the invoice_items table - but it's not doing this because both are left joins. A derived table will resolve this easily, and give the result that you want. I also added some table aliases for conciseness and readability.

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, SUM(inv.amount) AS total_revenue

FROM 
    products p  LEFT JOIN 

    (SELECT 
        ii.product, i.invoice_date, ii.amount 
     FROM 
        invoice_items ii JOIN
        invoices i ON 
            ii.invoice = i.id) inv ON 
            inv.product = p.id AND
            inv.invoice_date= current_date

GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: this did the trick, just change the ii.invoice_date on the derived table to i.invoice_date. Thanks :*

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a large number of NULL values, which seems expected based on your query.

This seems like it is an "INNER" join type of problem instead of a "left" join. Left join will keep all of the instances where there are no invoices for a product in the result set.

You can also move the entire query about "DATE" into the having clause (personally, I prefer subqueries in WHERE/Having as I find the logic clearer):

```
SELECT products.id, SUM(invoice_items.amount) AS total_revenue
FROM products
    INNER JOIN invoice_items ON invoice_items.product = products.id
HAVING EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM invoices WHERE invoice_items.invoice = invoices.id
                      AND invoices.invoice_date= current_date)
GROUP BY products.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see.  A smaller sample data with desired results would be helpful.

The problem is a bit complicated to explain.  The `left join` is keeping all products and invoices, regardless of date.  The final join to `invoices` is bringing in invoices that only match on the current date.  However, because you are summing on the second table, each matched row appears once (even if there are no invoice items for the day) and it appears in your results.

The solution:  Use a `case` statement to determine if there is a match in the `invoice` items table:

```
select p.id,
       sum(ii.amount * (case when i.id is not null then 1 end)) as total_revenue
from products p left join
     invoice_items ii
     on ii.product = p.id left join
     invoices i
     on ii.invoice = i.id and i.invoice_date = current_date
group by p.id;
```

I also suspect that the right condition for the date is:

```
     on ii.invoice = i.id and i.invoice_date >= current_date and
        i.invoice_date < current_date + interval '1 day'
```

Also, writing this as a subquery saves the outer aggregation and should also fix the problem:

```
select p.*,
       (select sum(ii.amount)
        from invoice_items ii join
             invoices i
             on ii.invoice = i.id and i.invoice_date >= current_date and
                i.invoice_date < current_date + interval '1 day'
        where ii.product = p.id
       ) as total_revenue
from products p;
```

Comment: I would expect the performance of the example above, with a subquery in the main select, to be very poor once the tables hit any more than a trivial number of records. A derived table is likely to perform way better, as it only has to be computed once, not once for every product.

Comment: @SimonWoolf . . . With the right indexing, the subquery could be the fastest approach.

Comment: How so? That same indexing will also improve the performance of the derived table, which will always outrun this approach, in my experience.